# HTML update lag when Angular $scope variable changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I have an http request that grabs some data and applies it to a `$scope` variable:

```
$http.post("/api/division", 1).success(function(data){
  $scope.division = data;
});
```

Now in my HTML I iterate through that data and display various bits of information, for example:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="player in division">
  <div>{{player.name}}</div>
  <div>{{player.number}}</div>
  <div>{{player.score}}</div>
</div>
```

This works great. Now, I have a link that triggers a function to get a new set of data and bind it to the same $scope variable so the frontend will update with new information.

Get Division

```
$scope.getDivision = function(){
  $http.post("/api/division", 2).success(function(data){
    $scope.division = data;
  });
}
```

Now, the front end does update with the new information, but there seems to be a lag of 5-10 seconds between the data successfully coming back and the HTML updating. So the problem isn't with the speed of the server. Is it something to do with needing to `$emit` or `$broadcast` the change to the variable? How can I get rid of the lag?

Comment: Using `$emit` or `$broadcast` will not help performance (based on your code example).  If anything it will decrease performance due to the extra digest.

Comment: I think ti should be fine, maybe some issue with the fact that you update reference to array, not items in there. I would try wrapping code into $timeout call. `$timeout(function(){$scope.division = data}, 0);`

Comment: How many players are in a division?

Comment: @DavinTryon 10 players in the division and each player has an object of about 10 bits of information. So in total, a multi-dimensional object with about 100 things in gets updated to the `$scope.division`

Comment: There really should be no problem with than much data.  Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: Yes all browsers although lag isn't as bad in some. I have some other code that executes some UI things in the success callback of the http request. Those thing execute immediately, so I know the data has come back is fine. Just not updating everything quick enough.

Comment: Since the function that is doing the $http.post is the same in both cases (apart from the second parameter 2) it's probably not to do with that bit of code. How is the link calling the function?

Comment: `<a href="" data-ng-click="getDivision()"></a>` but there's no lag between the link click and the $http request firing. The other UI stuff that fires in the success callback happens immediately. Only thing that lags is the HTML updating with the new data.

Comment: can you call digest?